# Adding map marker to floor plan in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a building floor plan image and what I intend to do with it is to put it as a 2D image on canvas. This I have no problem to do.

At certain place, say, at the front door, I want to put a marker of some sort (similar to Google Map marker, or blue/red pin) to mark it as sensor (i.e motion, etc..). If I click the marker it will display info on that particular sensor. How do I do this? I can't seem to find correct term to get the result that I want when I tried to google on this. I hope any of you can point me to the right direction on this.

Comment: This question is too broad for this site.  Narrow it down by trying something first, and then when you have a problem, come here.  Not before.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The thing is, I don't even know how to start to add the pin to my canvas. How do I even do that? I mean if it was from the Google Map, then I can do it.

Comment: Even that question is too broad.. that are many ways to do what you want, but if you want a suggestion of what api to try..  I would suggest the google maps api.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I've seen google maps api works only for Google Map. I was looking to put that on my house plan which I don't think google maps api support.

Comment: You're wrong.  I've seen variants of it used for things like minecraft.  Google Minecraft overviewer if you don't believe me.. point is though, you can use it for more than just maps.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. That's just what I need to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first thing, I didn't even know the term image tiles but after looking into Minecraft overviewer, suggested by Daedalus it looks like I have to create the image tiles. This can be done by using MapTiler software which can be obtained from [here](http://www.maptiler.org/). In the option, I just choose "Image Based Tiles" which suits me just fine.

After that I edited the HTML file generated with OpenLayer APIs to display the zooms and the markers and their [popups](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html). So, that's it.